# I have this error in Android Studio: Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

When I try to build my Gradle folder, the terminal systematically displays:

Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'.

Possible causes:

Your project may be using a version of the Android Gradle plugin that does not contain the method (for example, 'testCompile' was added in version 1.1.0).

Update the plugin to version 8.3.0 and synchronize the project.
Open Gradle wrapper file
Apply Gradle plugin

When I change the project version, I systematically get this message. Do you know how to avoid this problem?

Thank you

[first error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2Vdi.png)

I've updated the Android Gradle plug-in but it still can't find the compile() method.
When I replace compile by implementation, I get another error that tells me :[after modification compile()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTZU6.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwiAX.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCvZd.png)

And now I don't know how to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to update your **build.gradle** file. The `compile()` method has been **deprecated** and replaced with '`implementation`' or '`api`' depending on your use case.

Example:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    // Add other dependencies here with 'implementation'.
}
```

Remember to **sync** your project after making these changes to ensure they take effect.